# Derivation of fermionic partition function, how does commutation work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function

When deriving the fermionic partition function with coherent states $|\psi\rangle$ we make the following step

$$
\mathcal Z=\int d(\bar\psi,\psi)\ e^{-\sum_i\bar\psi_i \psi_i}\sum_n\langle n|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|e^{-\beta(\hat H - \mu\hat N)}|n\rangle\tag{1}
$$

$$
\mathcal Z=\int d(\bar\psi,\psi)\ e^{-\sum_i\bar\psi_i \psi_i}\sum_n\langle \zeta\psi|e^{-\beta(\hat H - \mu\hat N)}|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle\tag{2}
$$

Why does this work, why can we just commute the brakets and where does the $\zeta=-1$ come from?

Comment: $\langle n|\psi\rangle=\langle 0|a_{i1} .... a_{in}|\psi\rangle=\psi_{i1}...\psi_{in}$ Are grassman numbers

Comment: What is the meaning of $\langle \zeta \psi|$|?

Comment: $\langle -\psi|=\langle 0|\exp({\Sigma_i (-\bar{\psi}_ia_i)})$ Its basically a coherent state with a minus.